# Can Psychometabolism's Shared effect vary parameters between targets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

The Pathfinder [psion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion/) has discipline abilities as part of its kit. The 8th level Egoist ability allows the psion to share *Personal* psychometabolism powers with others.

Can the parameters of the powers vary between targets?

Say I manifest Metamorphisis. Can I turn myself into a cat and another target into a dog? Or say we are morphing into humanoids for the purposes of disguise and/or deception. What are the chances we don't have to end up as perfect look-alikes?

Comment: Shared effect borrows its wording from the psicrystal’s share powers, which comes directly from the D&D 3.5e version, and is based on the D&D 3.5e familiar. So this question is ultimately the same as “In D&D 3.5e, if I share *polymorph* with my familiar, can I turn myself into a cat and the familiar into a dog?” But I don’t know the answer to that question, either... (The PF familiar’s share spells is different, so doesn’t provide any guidance.)

Comment: @KRyan is correct. I asked just that question [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109829/8610)

Comment: Ah. Pathfinder is a bit looser with types when it comes to polymorphing. It's a bit amusing that both questions involve polymorph effects, tho perhaps understandable since most spells/powers don't have effects that can vary. I would strongly argue that the least dysfunctional way would be to allow variance, but I don't have even a whiff of a hint rule-wise. And also the least annoying at the table.

Comment: @martixy where is the pathfinder psion located?

Comment: Edited post with link to pfsrd @JamesRisner